# why are all the strings of Netflix's css not valid?

Tags: css, web-inspector, firefox-developer-edition

While looking at the code of some sites including Netflix and W3Schools, I noticed something odd: when looking at some elements (by clicking Inspect Element in Firefox Developer Edition), almost all of the CSS rules/strings were crossed out. Why would that be?
I attached two screenshots, 1 shows many crossed lines and 2 shows what element I was expecting.[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eRwT6.png)
[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iMjnp.jpg)

Comment: They use `Vendor Prefix` for browsers compatibility (Chrome, firefox, mozila etc). In case one fails the other will take place. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Vendor_Prefix

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The majority of those rules crossed out are fallbacks for specific browsers.

`-webkit` is Chrome and Safari,
`-moz` is Firefox,
`-o` is Opera and
`-ms` for Internet Explorer.

Comment: Interesting! How can I see which of those it is? And where are the rules that **are** written with -moz?

Answer (score 0):

Crossed out does not mean invalid, but *not applied*. That a value is not applied could be because it is not valid, or because it is overwritten by an other rule.

The values for `left` and `right` are valid, but they are not applied, because they are overwritten by another rule.